# EmEditor: Is EmEditor able to filter in a file without opening it?

Tags: emeditor

Is EmEditor able to filter in a file without opening it, like it does with find and replace in a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please select `Direct Open as Filter` from `Open As` drop-down list in the `Find in Files` dialog box.